# while loop inside foreach - what i'm doing wrong

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop

I'm very new to php and have tried to find solution myself but failed.  here is the code

```
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
$lastchange = 0;
$pricearray = array();
$onlyprices = array();
foreach ($mymainlist as $key => $val)
{
    $pricearray[$val] = $res[$val];   
    $avg = array_sum($pricearray[$val]) / count($pricearray[$val]); $onlyprices = array_values($pricearray[$val]) ;
    $dealmetric = ($avg - $onlyprices[$i])/ $avg * 100; 

    do { 
        if ($onlyprices[$i] === $onlyprices[$j]) { $j++; }
        else { $lastchange = $onlyprices[$j]; }
    } while ( $lastchange = 0 );
}
    echo $lastchange . '</br>';
```

the array $onlyprices look like this

```
Array ( [0] => 214.68 [1] => 214.68 [2] => 214.68 [3] => 217.96 [4] => 217.96 [5] => 217.96 [6] => 217.96 [7] => 217.96 [8] => 279.99 [9] => 221.63 [10] => 280.61 [11] => 269.99 [12] => 298.00 )
```

What I'm trying to do is to check when the first element is not equal to next elemrnt and return it.

So in the array above $lastchange, should return 217.96 , since  [0]=[1] and [0]=[2]

THANKS

Comment: `while ( $lastchange = 0 );` You are binding a value to `$lastchange` if you want to check some do it with `==` or `===`

Comment: Just to clarify: $lastchange = 0 is setting $lastchange at the end of every loop - you need to compare it $lastchange == 0

Comment: thanks , I did but now I have another problem: look in this array

Array ( [0] => 349.18 [1] => 362.18 [2] => 362.18 [3] => 362.18 [4] => 362.18 [5] => 377.65 [6] => 329.00 [7] => 414.70 [8] => 329.00 [9] => 414.70 [10] => 319.00 ) 

instead of returning 362.18  it returns number [5] 377.65

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
$lastchange = 0;
$pricearray = array();
$onlyprices = array();

foreach ($mymainlist as $key => $val) {
    $pricearray[$val] = $res[$val];   
    $avg = array_sum($pricearray[$val]) / count($pricearray[$val]);
    $onlyprices = array_values($pricearray[$val]) ;
    $dealmetric = ($avg - $onlyprices[$i])/ $avg * 100; 

    do { 
        if ($onlyprices[$i] === $onlyprices[$j]) { 
            $j++; 
        } else { 
            $lastchange = $onlyprices[$j]; 
        }
    } while ($lastchange == 0);

    echo $lastchange . '</br>'; 
}
```

In your code, your while condition is assigning the value 0 to the variable $lastcange.

You're not comparing the two.